# inheritInChildApplications stops inheritance in child web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I've experienced that adding a `< location inheritinchildapplications="false">` doesn't do what it implies.

The setting name implies that the settings set within this tag are not inherited by child APPLICATIONS. This is not the behavior I am experiencing. In my experience, the `inheritance` of the settings `stop` as soon as `another web.config` is encountered in deeper folder in the SAME application.

This above behavior is a problem for us. We have a large web application with subparts that have their own `web.config` that sets settings specific for this part of the application.

We want to have the entire application inherit the settings set in the `root web.config` of the application, but don't let child APPLICATIONS (so virtual dirs that have been marked as a separate application in `IIS`) inherit the settings. Is this possible, and if so, how? If not, is there any other implementation we can use to accomplish the desired result?

Comment: I read the following "you could make that sub-folder a stand-alone virtual application, in which case it wouldn't inherit any of the settings from the parent; in this scenario, it would also execute in its own app pool" but it doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: This is actually the scenario i am talking about. Sometimes our customers install other web applications within our web application, which causes the issues i am talking about. We are still looking for a solution to prevent any setting we set in our web.config to be inherited in child APPLICATIONS